# Google Maps don't fully load

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a somewhat strange problem. I have two maps on my site, a big one and a small one. I want to use the big one to show a route to a certain address. I'm now trying to implement the two maps but get a weird problem. The small map is working fine, but on the big map only a small area of the div is filled with the map, the rest is empty. (See the image.)

[image: Google Maps error]

I use the following code to display the two maps:

```
   function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.92475, 4.38206);
    var myOptions = {zoom: 10, center: latlng,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map:map, title:"Home"});
    var image = '/Core/Images/Icons/citysquare.png';
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.92308, 4.47058);
    var cityCentre = new google.maps.Marker({position:myLatLng, map:map, icon:image, title:"Centre"});
    marker.setMap(map);

    var largeLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.92475, 4.38206);
    var largeOptions = {zoom: 10, center: largeLatlng,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
    var largeMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("largeMap"), largeOptions);
    var largeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: largeLatlng, map:largeMap, title:"Cherrytrees"});
    largeMarker.setMap(largeMap); 
   }
   [..]
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    [..]
    initialize();
   });
```

What's going wrong here?

**EDIT:**

Unfortunately the suggestions below doesn't seem to work. The closes i came is to remove the *display:none* from the elements and set the elements to hide with jquery

```
   [..]
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    [..]
    $("#shadow").add($("#shadowContent"),$("#closebar"),$("#content")).hide();
   });
```

With the following result
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it!

I made an own function for the largemap and placed it in the callback when the elements are opened

```
function largeMap(){
 var largeLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.92475, 4.38206);
 var largeOptions = {zoom: 10, center: largeLatlng,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
 var largeMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("largeMap"), largeOptions);
 var largeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: largeLatlng, map:largeMap, title:"Cherrytrees"});
 largeMarker.setMap(largeMap);
}
[..]
 $("#showRoute").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#shadow").add($("#shadowContent"),$("#closebar"),$("#content")).fadeIn(500);
  $("#shadowContent").show().css({'width':'750px','top':'25px','left':'50%','margin-left':'-400px'});
  $("#closeBarLink").click(function(l){
   l.preventDefault();
   $("#shadow").add($("#shadowContent"),$("#closebar"),$("#content")).fadeOut(500);
  });
  largeMap();
 });
```

Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 15):

Yes, @Argiropoulos-Stavros but, Add it as a listener

```
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        map.setCenter(location);
    });
```

It will begin re-sizing after, map rendered.

Comment: Yes adding a listener and then resize is making map to cover full div. thanks Mustafa.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are using v3.
So google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");

Also take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746608/google-maps-not-rendering-completely-on-page)

Comment: Doesn't seem to to work. I tried it almost everywhere (before the end of teh function, after the function, in the load part) but with no result.. Still the weird square

Answer (score 2):

call `initialize();`  function after you box active.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#shadow").show(function () {
    initialize();
  })
});
```

Comment: I based my solution from this, just re-initialize when my hidden div with my map was toggled/displayed! Ty

Answer (score 1):

When you're loading in the large map, try adding this at the end of your map code.

```
map.checkResize();
```

When Google Maps first renders on your page, it has the dimensions recorded so that it displays the map images in that size. If you're resizing the map dynamically, you need to tell the API to check the new size.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. See my edited post though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript' >
var geocoder, map;
function codeAddress() {
    var address= '<?php echo $this->subject()->address; ?>';
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 13,
                center: results[0].geometry.location,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                icon:'http://rvillage.com/application/themes/rvillage/images/map-marker.png'
            }); 
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: 'coming soon' });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, this);         
            });
        }
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    codeAddress();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using pop up window with jQuery, and I guest you call `initialize()` function when document is ready ( `$(document).ready(function() {initialize(); })` ). 
Try call `initialize()` function after pop up windown showed.

Johnny