# Google Maps returning longitude >180 in LatLng.toUrlValue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am building a global map with overlay polygons. It is inside a jQuery Accordion. Whenever I switch accordion panes and then come back to the map, it jumps down to Antarctica. To overcome this behavior, I have been trying to capture the current center LatLng, store it in a variable, then setCenter() when returning to the map's accordion panel.

It didn't work, so I tried using the .toUrlValue() method to dump the current center coordinates to a visible element on the page. As I pan the map east or west, the longitude number just keeps incrementing. I expected it to go to 180 then reset to -180.

[image: map longitude problem]

My code:

```
var currMapCenter = null;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#accordion").bind('accordionchange', function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.newContent.attr('id') == 'region-list')
    {
    triggerMapResize(); 
    }
});
});

function initialize_map() {

//do all the initialization here...

currMapCenter = map.getCenter(); //set initial center in variable.

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
  currMapCenter=map.getCenter();
  jQuery("#description").html(currMapCenter.toUrlValue());//to see what is happening...
});
}

function triggerMapResize()
{
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
map.setCenter(currMapCenter);
}
```

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) indicates getCenter() returns a LatLng, and setCenter() requires a LatLng. Am I misunderstanding what happens when I try to set currMapCenter = map.getCenter()?  Given that my map needs to wrap as it currently does, how do I capture a usable LatLng to use with setCenter()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems now that the title of this topic is inaccurate and irrelevant to the actual problem. IE8 - no surprise - was giving me all sorts of problems and failing to draw the map at all, while standards-compliant browsers were fine except the loss of center when switching accordion panes.

In my original code, I was listening for the 'center_changed' event to capture the current map center coordinates. I started wondering if jQuery's events were altering the position of the map as the accordion closed, so I switched the center capture event to 'mouseout'. This solved the problem, though I still don't know what caused it.

side-note: I had been using window.onload = function () { initialize_map(); } with success in browsers other than IE, but IE choked and wouldn't load at all.

```
var map=null;
var currMapCenter = null;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#accordion").bind('accordionchange', function(event, ui) {
if (ui.newContent.attr('id') == 'region-list')
{
if(map==null) {
//first load; call map initialization
initialize_map();
}
triggerMapResize(); 
}
});

function initialize_map() {

//do initilization here...

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseout', function() { 
currMapCenter=map.getCenter();
});
}

function triggerMapResize() {
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
map.setCenter(currMapCenter);
}
```

The above code works without a problem; tested in Firefox 14, Chrome and IE8.

Answer (score 3):

getCenter() returns LatLng, but it could be more than 180 degrees. It depends on how many times you rotate the earth around its axis. :)

I found simple fix for this problem

```
var loc=map.getCenter();
loc=new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat(), loc.lng(), false);
```

Now LatLng is recalculated to proper values and you can use it ...

Comment: This works great. It is too bad you can't just pass a `wrap` flag to `getCenter` and skip this but oh well

Answer (score 1):

The that behavior is documented for the [Map object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) getCenter method

getCenter()
LatLng
Returns the position displayed at the center of the map. Note that this **LatLng object is not wrapped**. See LatLng for more information.

Maybe you can use getBounds() (might not work if the map is zoomed out to show multiple copies)

getBounds()
LatLngBounds
Returns the lat/lng bounds of the current viewport. If more than one copy of the world is visible, the bounds range in longitude from -180 to 180 degrees inclusive.

Comment: I had seen that in the Map object section, but didn't understand what 'is not wrapped' implied as far as reassigning it to the map. I was trying to find a way to make it wrapped (-180 to 180), but maybe that doesn't matter. I think it's the jQuery actions that are throwing the map center off as it switches accordion panes.

Comment: Triggering the "resize" event on the map after you display it doesn't work? The documentation says "resize - Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div changes size: google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')."  You are effectively changing the size of the map when you hide it.

Comment: The resize event cured my original problem of the map being only partially drawn ( as described in [another SO topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838580/google-map-comes-partially-grey-area-comes-instead-of-images-from-google-server)  .) Even after that was in place, though, it did not retain the center position.  I found a solution last night and will post it when I get the relevant code prepped.

Comment: LatLng constructor has an optional argument wrap, you could take coords you get and create ne LatLng object with them, passing true as optional argument

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this thread helped me. This is the code I used to verify the noWarp setting and access the center that I required without the coordinates going over the +/- 180 degrees :-

```
var gmap_center = new google.maps.LatLng(map.getCenter().lat(), map.getCenter().lng(), false);

console.log('GMap lat/lng with default noWrap:true = ' + map.getCenter().lat() + ' / ' + map.getCenter().lng());

console.log('GMap lat/lng with noWrap:false = ' + gmap_center.lat() + ' / ' + gmap_center.lng());
```