# Firefox Issue with Google.Map Tiles

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firefox

While viewing the `google.maps.Map` on `firefox` the tiles don't seem to line up correctly.

[image: Firefox Google Tiles]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/dgag2lnp.0g3.png))</sub>

But I'm getting the expected result while viewing the map within `Google Chrome`

[image: Google Chrome]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/2txmdv4n.zoc.png))</sub>

Javascript is based off source from [Google Simple Map](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple)

I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/killrawr/kahtepL5/) (based off code, from the website in question).

The fiddle seems to load fine in firefox, but when the same code is loaded on the website (UTF-8 Character Set, the tiles seem to overlay and break).

Comment: What version of Firefox?  What version of the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior probably is similar to [described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838580/google-map-comes-partially-grey-area-comes-instead-of-images-from-google-server).

If so, the solution would be to explicitly invoke `resize`  event:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

**Example**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    initMap();

});

var map;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('details_map_item'), {
        center: {
            lat: -34.397,
            lng: 150.644
        },
        zoom: 8
    });


    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });
}
```

```css
#details_con,
#details_map{
    margin:0 2px 0 0;
    padding:10px;   
    list-style:none;
    background:#fff;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    font-size:14px;
}


#details_map{
    max-width:610px;
    padding:12px;   
    margin:20px auto;
    line-height:1;
}

div#details_map_item {
    height:300px;
    /* width:400px; */
    background: #69C none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<div id="details_map">
   <div id="details_map_item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I worked around it, using an iframe. Separating the styles between windows. But +1 for the answer anyway, I'm sure it will help someone else who may come across the same issue.