# Google map does not load when displayed onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, google-maps

My google map is hidden and it is displayed using `ng-show` when I click on a previous button. The problem is that it does not load / initialize. It just stays grayed out. I've tried `"resize"` but does nothing. I've tried using `onclick="displayMap()"` and using display `none/block` but it's not working either. No console errors.

Comment: Well, it suppose to. Are you sure you call the resize **after** the `ng-show` shows the map? Maybe not, Try to call the resize method with `setTimeout` after the `ng-show` condition is true. Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6596864/863110) answer, maybe it will help.

Comment: setTimeout doesn't work, but I may not be doing it correctly.. I am at a loss. :S

Comment: As much as I saw, the `ng-show` is this, `!validacion12()`, right? And did you try to call the resize after this function?

Comment: Resize is inside initMap(). I tried initMap() inside the conditional from validacion12() (which is in another file) but it doesn't work either. Result is: $scope.validacion12 = function()
 {
  if( $scope.codigo_regalo != null && $scope.codigo_regalo != "" && $scope.codigo_regalo == $scope.codigo_regalo_valido )
  {
   $scope.novalid1 = "false";
   displayMap();
   return false;
  }
  else
  {
   $scope.novalid1 = "true";
   return true;
  }
 };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue (see for example [here](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/maps/7tV5PZiD_gA/enZtSDhzAAAJ)), the map size is not properly determined once the parent div `display` style is set to `none`. Both [`ng-hide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)/[`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) directives hides/shows the given element by manipulating display style.

One solution would be to replace `ng-show` with [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)/[`ng-style`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) directives to control the map visibility as demonstrated below:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MapCtrl', [
        '$scope', function ($scope) {

            $scope.mapIsVisible = false;


            $scope.toggleMap = function(){
                $scope.mapIsVisible = !$scope.mapIsVisible;
            };


            $scope.initMap = function () {
                var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.870501, 151.206704);
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 12,
                    center: center,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
                };
                $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
             
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', $scope.initMap);
        }]);
```

```css
 #map-canvas {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>



  <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="MapCtrl">
            <button ng-click="toggleMap()">Toggle map</button>
            <div ng-style="{'visibility': mapIsVisible ? 'visible':'hidden'}">
                <div id="map-canvas"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it does initialize now doing it like in your example, but when I input a city, it does not show the marker (nor the circle surrounding it) and if I move around the map then some parts remain grayed out, so it's like it only initializes once but then stops working.. I guess I'm gonna need to ask another question with this issue now.

Comment: @JJCarlk3, it sounds like a different issue so creating  a separate question would be a good idea

Comment: Okay I don't know what happened but now it won't work even once. :S

Answer (score 0):

You can use `callback` for this..

```
function displayMap(){
    jQuery("#mapDiv").fadeIn("fast",function(){
        initMap();
    });
}
```

Comment: callback? how? like this? <script src="maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[key]&libraries=places&language=es&callback=initMap" async defer></script> The code above does nothing unfortunately. :/