# map not loaded on a HTML code received through ajax request

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, google-maps

I am building my own personalweb (and my first webpage) and I'm having some troubles trying to display a google map.

First of all, I will try to explain my case. my webpage has four links that load the HTML code of each section inside a div. Because of i dont want to refresh my webpage everytime a link is clicked, That HTML code is recieved through an AJAX request. When a section called 'contact me' is clicked, i call the *initialize* method to load the map inside a div that has been created in the new HTML code recieved via AJAX.  Of course I call *initialize* after the HTML code is recieved.

Everything seems to work fine, but it only does when I click the link for the first time. When I do, I can see the map; but when I go to another section and then I click again on 'contact me' I see the div but the map is gone:

http://s8.postimg.org/9rllxtxed/map_error.jpg // I dont have enough reputation yet to post images.

This is the *initialize* function:

```
 function initialize() {
    var target_div = document.getElementById("map"); //This is the ID of the div created on the HTML code recieved through AJAX.
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(65.6516152,-34.7739923),
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(target_div,mapOptions); //*map* is a global variable (one of my many tries to resolve it)
 }
```

And this is the function that calls AJAX requests  and *initialize* to display the content in a div called *reciever_div*:

```
    function open_section(clicked_link) {
    if (actual_link != null){
        actual_link = clicked_link;
        reciever_div.fadeOut(750,function(){
            reciever_div.html('');
            $.ajax({
               url: 'textos/'+clicked_link+'.txt',
                success: function (recieved_file) {
                    reciever_div.html(recieved_file);
                    if (clicked_link == 'contactme') {
                        initialize();
                    }
                    reciever_div.fadeIn(750);
                }
            });
        });
    }
   else{
    actual_link = clicked_link;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'textos/'+ clicked_link + '.txt',
        success: function(recieved_file){
            reciever_div.html(recieved_file);
             if (clicked_link == 'contactme') {
                console.log(clicked_link);
                initialize();
                    }
            reciever_div.fadeIn(1500);
        } 
    })
   }
}
```

Do you know why is this happening, or a better way to implement this? I'm a noob, and i dont know if i'm asking too much to ajax requests, css or what.

thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have any error in the javascript console(Te da algún error en la consola de Chrome?También dale un ojo a las peticiones en la ventana Network)

Comment: No error in console, and I am not familiarized with the network window on chrome, but i dont see any kind of error or warning.

Comment: Is this a live site...can you give me the url(así puedo ver los errores de manera específica, soy de Chile btw )

Comment: De momento no está online ni tengo modo de subirlo a un servidor, trabajo en   local : (

Comment: Try https://jsfiddle.net/ (Maquetea tu código ahí, lo guardas y posteas el link, asi podemos reproducir el error).

Comment: Lo he estado intentando, pero no logro hacer funcionar las peticiones ajax, me parece que tengo una estructura demasiado compleja para simularla sin tener conocimientos de jsfiddle.net, pero muchas gracias.

Comment: Okaps man...saludos :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made my research and the grey map is probably caused by some strange css or execution flow behaviour. I realized that if I opened Chrome's console the map loaded again, and searching info i found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358582/google-map-shows-only-partially). I changed the initialize method to execute after a **setTimeout** of 2 seconds and it works fine. I still dont get why this is not needed for the first time I click the link but it is for the following ones, but it does.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your first problem related to the grey google maps image i related to the fact you can't create more the one time the maps. I have the same situation in the past and i have solved checking flag before create the first time the map this way

```
function setMapTarget () {
    if (! flagMapTarget){
        flagMapTarget = true;
        ......
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_prg'), mapPrgOptions);
```

Comment: I tried, but when i do that and reload the section the div does not appear: s18.postimg.org/5d1bqoukp/map_error2.jpg (well, speaking properly, it is created from zero, because when the section was closed his HTML code was deleted).

Comment: the section is visible or is hidden. if is hidden try adding ` google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` after creation. could be "refresh" problem and sometime this solve the problem

Comment: It does not work, I said that the div is deleted, not just hidden, because when I close the 'contact me' section the div gets clean (receiver_div.html('')) so when I click again on 'contact me' section it does not change the css visibility property, instead , it creates it from zero.